# If the cardinality of two sets is the same, then when are the two sets equal?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Take $A, B$ as finite sets. As graciously explained below, this question fails for infinite sets.
>   What are all conditions that effect: $|A| = |B| \implies A = B$ ?
>   By inspection, the converse is trivially true.

For example, if $A \subseteq B$ is also true, then the given that $|A| = |B|$ effects  $A = B.$

For another way to construe this, I try a proof by contrapositive.
Since $A = B \quad  \equiv \quad [A\subseteq B] \quad \wedge \quad [B \subseteq A]$, thus $\color{tomato}{\neg}[A = B] \quad  \equiv \quad A\subsetneq B \quad \vee \quad B \subsetneq A$.
WLOG, say $A \subsetneq B$. Then $A$ must have fewer elements than $B$. Thus $|A| \neq |B|$.

**Supplementary dated Mar 6 2014 :** Does my writing above prove the contents of amWhy's sterling answer? Or are there better manners to prove it?

Comment: This is only true if the sets are finite of course. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we are given that $A, B$ are **finite** sets such that $|A| = |B|$, and if we know that $A \subseteq B$ **or** $B \subseteq A$, *then* we can conclude $A = B$.

Usually to prove that $A = B$, we need to prove that **both** $A\subseteq B$ AND $B\subseteq A$.

In this case, given finite $A, B$ with $|A| = |B|$, it suffices to show only one of the containments.

Note that the *finite* condition is necessary, the above isn't true of infinite sets. For example, take $A = \mathbb Z$, $B = \mathbb Q$.  Then both sets have the same cardinality, and $\mathbb Z \subseteq \mathbb Q$, but clearly $\mathbb Z \neq \mathbb Q$.

**ADDED:** To address the amended post, I think the contrapositive prefaced "for another way to construe this, ..." is the most succinct way to drive this relationship home.

Indeed, if $A$ and $B$ are both finite sets and $(A \subsetneq B) \text{ or } (B\subsetneq A)$, then we know by definition of a proper subset that $$\Big((\forall a \in A (a \in B)) \land (\exists b \in B (b\notin A))\Big) \lor \Big((\forall b \in B(b \in A)) \land (\exists a \in A(a \notin B))\Big)$$ 
Therefore it is necessarily the case that $$|A| \lt |B|,\quad\text{or}\quad |B|\lt |A|$$

In either case, it follows that $|A|\neq |B|$.

Comment: +1: This is a simple and very useful case of what the OP is asking about.  I can't think of another case which is nearly as useful.

Comment: +1. Thank you very much. As a supplementary, I'd like to ask about the proof of this. Is my writing in my OP correct? Or are there better manners to prove it? I'd be grateful if you would please advise in your answer.

Comment: +1. Thank you very much again. I think you had meant "construe" in my OP instead of "put", thus I changed this. The other incidental edit was merely to add "for" which I had just done in my OP. Please advise me about any objections or the edit.

Answer (score 1):

Just for giving you another counter example, assuming you passed a good course about `set theory`: $$\text{card}{(\mathbb N_{\text{e}})}=\aleph_0=\text{card}{(\mathbb N)}$$ where $\mathbb N_{\text{e}}$ is the set of all even natural numbers.

Comment: +1. Thank you very much. I haven't studied set theory per se.